# Java Swing GUI Moving frame and dialogue box together from one desktop screen to another

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

hey I have been given a 128 page code of java including java swing components to make a GUI so the task is .... the frame is there and the dialogue box(JOPTIONPANE)is also poppin up correctly but when am moving my frame onto another screen/deskptop  the dialogue box is not moving with it What should i do ??

Comment: What do you mean by 'when I am moving my frame onto another screen/desktop the dialogue box is not moving with it"? A JOptionPane is a modal dialog, and therefore when it is displaying, the underlying JFrame cannot be dragged. Do you mean when you move the JFrame to the secondary display and then show the JOptionPane, that it pops up on the primary display?

If this is the case, you probably don't set the JFrame as the parent of the JOptionPane. When you do, the JOptionPane shows up on the same display as the parent frame. Without a parent, it shows up in the center of the primary display.

Comment: m sorry i was not clear enough to explain but i got my answer thank you so much ...

Comment: BTW can you help me with one more thing can u write an example code to show how to make jframe as a Parent plz